# Run Edge headless mode in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I found few solutions in java and python about passing `headless option` to edge webdriver. But I need to do it in *pure* Robot Framework. Is it possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `SeleniumLibrary` in Robot Framework, the headless option is not supported for edge webdriver. You can refer to this [document](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Open%20Browser). The document says "Headless Firefox and Headless Chrome are new additions in SeleniumLibrary 3.1.0 and require Selenium 3.8.0 or newer."

However, you can try `Browser`. Here is [Link](https://robotframework-browser.org/#introduction). It can use Edge with the `headless option`. I executed it on Ubuntu and works.

**Code Example**

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Browser

*** Tasks ***
Open Browser With Headless Option
    Open Browser    url=https://www.google.com/    browser=chromium    headless=true
```